# Spring webpage - injecting response token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm fairly new to spring security. I've made basic database with tables for users and roles and included registration and login DTO in my project. My question is: when I log-in and get response token, how do I make it injected each time I redirect to another url(to not login everytime) + I would like to redirect to home page in same PostMapping method as well

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/auth/registerSuccess")
    public ApplicationUser registerUser(ApplicationUser user){
        return authenticationService.registerUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/loginSuccess")
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(ApplicationUser user){
        return authenticationService.loginUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

    }


//    @PostMapping("/auth/loginSuccess")
//    public String redirectLogin(){
//        return "index";
//    }

//    @PostMapping("/auth/registerSuccess")
//    public String redirectRegister(){
//        return "index";
//    }



    @GetMapping("/auth/register")
    public String registerUser(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new ApplicationUser());
        return "register";
    }


    @GetMapping("/auth/login")
    public String loginUser(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new ApplicationUser());
        return "login";
    }
    

}
```

I've tried to change return types for String in order to at least redirect to html files but it doesn't solve my main issue with injecting token.

Comment: what is a `response token` if you mean i `JWT` then you are building a very insecure login system. You should never issue JWTs directly to the browser. Please google why jwts should not be used as sessions, and instead implement security using cookies as stated in the spring security documentation.

Comment: Thanks for advice altough this one is just for educational purposes and I just want to establish working session by injecting jwt tokens for at least minimum security

Comment: if your plan is to learn security i suggest you learn it properly from the start. Read the spring security docs and dont follow blogposts that have no idea how security works.